# Understanding op amp specifications

Tags: operational-amplifier

I am looking through various op amps under DigiKey. I was having trouble understanding the 3 specifications of the op amp listed below:

1. What does "Current-Supply" mean? Is this the maximum amount of differential current that the op amp can take from both terminals?
2. Does the specification values for "Current - Output/Channel" mean the output current with no feedback resistor to amplify the signal?
3. How do I interpret the values and ranges provided under "Voltage-Supply,Single/Dual (+-)"? Is this the range of voltages that the op amp can be supplied with without breaking down/frying? If there is an additional range provided, does this mean the op amp is dual supply? If so, what does the +/- imply?

[image]

Comment: They are telling you what the typical quiescent current (inactive, no load) is, the output compliance current (how much the output can handle as a limit), and the range of operating voltages over which it may work.

Comment: so even by signal amplification using a feedback resistor of choice, the maximum current output for the op amp in the first row is 30mA?

Also, if the operating voltage range is 2.5V ~ 5.5V, can I set the op amp using dual voltage supply? or strictly single supply?

Comment: Yeah, opamps generally don't put out better than 25 mA. Often less than that. You won't be driving speakers with them! There are some that can handle a lot more. But they are unusual and often expensive. The gist is that if you need higher current compliance, then there's power involved and you probably should use external parts for that, anyway. Read the datasheet. But if all I see at Digikey is 5.5 V then this means to me it's either single supply or else it's really small dual supply! That maximum number is a "stand-off" kind of value. You don't stress it more than that.

Comment: Thanks, that clears it up a lot. What does the voltage range of 4.5V~15.5V, +-2.25V~+-7.75V mean? From what I can see, the op amp operates safely at a range of 4.5V to 15.5V, but what does the second range with +- mean?

Comment: Though I should read the datasheet before jumping to answer you, I'd guess that it's kind of obvious. If you run a dual supply rail then don't use more than +/- 7.75 V but if you are using this in a single supply rail case, grounding the (-) rail side, then you can go up to 15.5 V on the (+) rail. Again, it's "stand-off" -- that device can stand off 15.5 V without collapsing important bits inside it, however you apply it.

Comment: Right I see. Just finally, for instance in the first row, if there was less than 1.3mA applied to the negative terminal of the op amp, while the positive terminal was grounded, will the op amp function?

Comment: You don't "apply 1.3 mA" to either rail of the opamp! (Now I know you have some learning to do as you've exposed more ignorance -- not a bad word, don't get me wrong -- than I'd anticipated.) You provide it's negative rail with a lower voltage, it's positive rail with a higher voltage, and then you expect that if you don't attach any other pins to anything, that you will read about 1.3 mA with an ammeter -- either into the (+) rail or out of the (-) rail as a typical but not necessarily guaranteed level. If you add a load to the output? Then things change!

Comment: I see, thank you so much for clarifying!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Supply current is the current needed by the op amp to operate. It is the amount of current drawn by the op amp when there is no load -- any additional load current is added to the "supply current". This column also indicates how many op amp channels are contained in the integrated circuit (IC).
2. Output current per channel is the maximum current that each channel of the op amp IC can provide to a load. If the load attempts to draw more than this current then the op amp will not be able to apply the desired output voltage. For example, if you attempt to apply 1 V to a 1 Ω load with an op amp that is limited to an output current of 30 mA you will only see 30 mV at the output.
3. The first set of numbers without the +/- indicate the acceptable range of supply voltages for a single supply. You must supply at least the minimum voltage or the op amp will not turn on, and you should not exceed the maximum in order to avoid damaging the op amp. The second set of numbers (with the +/-) indicate the acceptable range of dual supply voltages (assuming balanced supplies -- i.e. both are 1.5 V or both are 7.5 V). Note that all op amps can operate on dual supplies (and the supplies don't necessarily have to be balanced -- they just have to be within acceptable range min/max supply voltage range and the common mode range of the op amp), but not all op amps can operate with a single supply. A "single supply" op amp is one that can operate on signals all the way down to its negative supply voltage (i.e. its common mode range at the input and output extend to the negative supply rail).

Note that these numbers aren't necessarily completely accurate -- there are likely caveats and/or nuances in the datasheet which aren't captured in Digikey's tables. Digikey's table entries provide a good starting point for comparing parts but **you should always confirm specifications by checking the device's datasheet**.

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed answer, this clarifies it fully. If a single supply is used, it is common practice to bias the input to half the supply voltage right?

Comment: @Kevin Yes, that's most common. As long as the input is within the common mode input voltage range that's all that's *required*, though.